# function not call using window.frames in Internet explore

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular5

I want to call javascript function from another screen using **window.frames** but code run correct in chrome, mozila but not work in Internet Explorer

```
    //Typescript Function
    async AddQweGoogle() 
    {
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "/GoogleAddQwe/Index");
    ifrm.setAttribute("name", "frameName");
    ifrm.style.width = "0px";
    ifrm.style.height = "0px";
    if (document.getElementsByName('frameName').length == 0) {
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
    var practiceData = this.practiceData_clientSide;
    var s = window.frames['frameName'].qwe();
    }
```

I call Javascript function qwe() from **GoogleAddQwe/Index** in Typescript Function but this code not wonk only in Internet Explorere

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: version of IE is 11